# Output keeps on running

Tags: java

Why does the output keep on running? When I run this program, and I enter the in the output, it keeps running, and doesn't let me enter any more numbers. Why is this happening?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExceptionTest2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ab, bd, cde;
        ab = bd = cde = 0;
        boolean infinite, in;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the numbers to divide");
            infinite = false;
            in = true;
            try
            {
                ab = st.nextInt();
                bd = st.nextInt();
                infinite = false;
                in = true;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                in = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (in)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("I am in try block before exception");
                        cde = ab / bd;
                        System.out.println("I am in try block after exception");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        infinite = true;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (!infinite)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Answer is " + cde);
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (cde != 100);
        st.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line keeps running? Also, in the future, it would help you significantly to use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: what did you input? Maybe `cde` was never 100.

Comment: I just ran this, and it worked fine for me (well, other than giving me integer division results).  It allowed me to enter additional numbers to divide just fine.  Can you give us an example of your input, and an example of the output that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
ab = st.nextInt();
```

When you input a `String` on it I wont get consumed by the `nextInt` and no one will thus giving you infinite loop

**solution:**

You need to consume those characters that you inputted in your catch block to avoid the infinite loop

**sample:**

```
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("Invalid input");
               st.nextLine();
               in=true;
            }
```